# It's normal if user can log in without password/email but only just with cookie?

Tags: authentication, security, session, next.js, cookies

Hello I develop a website with next js and I have an issue. I use iron session for my session when I log in user. And backend create a cookie in browser to keep the user connected.

For exemple:

1. An user visit my site and log in with password / email -> the user in log.
2. I copy the cookie and put it in other browser and I refresh page -> the user in log (without email/password).

When user wants to log, the backend do this :

```
     req.session.user = userObject;
     await req.session.save();
     return res.status(200).json({
         status: 200,
         body: userObject,
     });
```

And I have a cookie in browser for check if user is log.

I wanted to know if this was normal and what the vulnerability is. How do you protect this? I saw the CSRF vulnerability but I don’t know if that’s it
Thank you for your help

Comment: This is normal, HTTP is a stateless protocol. The cookie is the way the server knows the user is connected, and who this user is. As long as you protect the cookie correctly (HttpOnly, SameSite, Secure), and it is both secure and generated truely randomly, you are good to go. You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see secure, same site and http only so it's good. I’ll find out more about this

Comment: And secure session against CSRF is important ?

Comment: It's always better to be really safe, so yes, it is. You can find more information here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/252300/do-i-still-need-a-csrf-token.